# Custom Command cannot use equation mode?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have defined a new command below, but when ever I pass an equation into, it will not work.

```
\newcommand{\defn}[1]{
{\textbf{Definition}}\\  
\parbox{5.2in}{\begin{flushright} \fbox{#1}\end{flushright} } }
```

This is what it allows me to do:

```
\defn{If $f$ is integrable over the interval $[a,b]$, we define $\int_{b}^{a} f(x)\ dx$ }
```

However, this is what I want to do:

```
\defn{If $f$ is integrable over the interval $[a,b]$, we define 
$$\int_{b}^{a} f(x)\ dx$$ }
```

Or alternatively,

```
 \defn{If $f$ is integrable over the interval $[a,b]$, we define 
  \begin{equation*}
    \int_{b}^{a} f(x)\ dx
  \end{equation}}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Why don't you just use the more standard solution using environment and theorem-like constructions, the `amsthm` package allows you to create theorem-like structures that are unnumbered. Then you also get the bonus of automatically added separation space above and below the construction

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\defn}[1]{%
\textbf{Definition:}\par  
\minipage{5.2cm}
#1
\endminipage
}

\begin{document}
 \defn{If $f$ is integrable over the interval $[a,b]$, we define 
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{b}^{a} f(x)\ dx
  \end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

You might also consider the following alternate definition, where you can set the size as we:

```
\newcommand{\defn}[2]{%
\textbf{Definition:}\par  
\hsize#1
#2
}
```